# Can ‘10 minus 3’ be interchanged by ‘10 with the subtraction of 3’?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, definition

10 is subtracted by 3

Can ‘10 minus 3’ be interchanged by ‘10 with the subtraction of 3’?

https://www.lexico.com/definition/minus

Is Lexico wrong? The other dictionaries says ‘deducted by’ and so on

Comment: Lexico defines *house* as "a building for human habitation", but nobody would ever substitute "a building for human habitation" for *house* in a sentence.

Comment: @The Photon Is Lexico stupid? Isn’t it from OED? Why is Lexico narrowsighted

Comment: there's nothing wrong with Lexico. No dictionary every has claimed that the definitions it presents can be substituted for the words they define in an arbitrary sentence.

Comment: If you want synonyms for a word, look in a thesaurus, not a dictionary.

Comment: @The Photon It’s not a matter of substitute. It’s a total mess! Who use ‘with’instead of action verbs

Comment: @The Photon Is it fine if I define ‘do’ as ‘with doing’? I’m mad at Lexico

Comment: @ssinal "Minus" is hardly a verb here.  Lexico says it is a preposition.  I think that is right.

Comment: @ssinal  Is there any more context?  Are you saying this as part of a sentence or a conversation?  Where are you trying to use this phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wouldn’t be how most native speakers would say it. However, they might say:

> 3 subtracted from 10

Not entirely related, but useful nevertheless: in terms of writing style, it is common practice to write numbers as words instead of numerals when they start a sentence. The same applies for numbers less than 100 (or 10, depending on the style being used). So, your sentences would then be:

> Ten minus three
>
> Three subtracted from ten

Comment: Interchangeable??????????

Comment: I don’t understand that.

Comment: but lexico says minus is with the subtraction of

Comment: Well Lexico is wrong. Or, giving them the benefit of the doubt: they are simply explaining the general *meaning* of “minus”; they are not giving you a direct replacement for it.